# Why does GROUP BY not work with created column in select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following script

```
SELECT  
    CASE
        WHEN Grade < 4 
            THEN 'Fail'
        WHEN Grade >=4 and Grade < 6 
            THEN 'C'
        WHEN Grade >=6  and Grade < 8
            THEN 'Ok'
        ELSE 'Exc.'
    END AS [Status],
    COUNT(Grade) AS v
FROM
    GradeList
GROUP BY 
    [Status]
```

And it doesn't see the column `Status`. Can't  get why, what's the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reuse calculated case column in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67864374/reuse-calculated-case-column-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 3):

That is how SQL Server (and SQL) are defined.  Column aliases defined in the `SELECT` are not available in the `FROM`, `WHERE`, or `GROUP BY` clauses.

There are multiple solutions for this.  My favorite is to use `APPLY` because this defines the aliases in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT v.Status, COUNT(*) as v
FROM GradeList gl CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN Grade < 4 THEN 'Fail'
                   WHEN Grade < 6 THEN 'C'
                   WHEN Grade < 8 THEN 'Ok'
                   ELSE 'Exc.'
              END)
     ) v(Status)
GROUP BY v.Status;
```

Note that this also simplifies the `CASE` logic.  The first matching condition is returned, so there is no need for `BETWEEN`.  That actually makes it much easier to add and remove conditions, if you want to tweak the query.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server processes the SQL Statment in a particular logical order. As SELECT clause comes after GROUP BY clause, GROUP BY clause does not see the column alias.

[Read more on the logical processing order on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement)

1. FROM
2. ON
3. JOIN
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP

You can go for derived table or Common Table Expression to get over this problem.

```sql
SELECT Status, COUNT(Grade) AS v
FROM
(
SELECT  
    CASE
        WHEN Grade < 4 
            THEN 'Fail'
        WHEN Grade >=4 and Grade < 6 
            THEN 'C'
        WHEN Grade >=6  and Grade < 8
            THEN 'Ok'
        ELSE 'Exc.'
    END AS [Status],
    Grade     
FROM
    GradeList
) AS g(Status,Grade)
GROUP BY 
    [Status]
```

```sql
;WITH cte_gradelist(Status,Grade) AS
(
SELECT  
    CASE
        WHEN Grade < 4 
            THEN 'Fail'
        WHEN Grade >=4 and Grade < 6 
            THEN 'C'
        WHEN Grade >=6  and Grade < 8
            THEN 'Ok'
        ELSE 'Exc.'
    END AS [Status],
    Grade     
FROM
    GradeList
)
SELECT Status, COUNT(Grade) AS v
FROM cte_gradelist
GROUP BY 
    [Status]
```