# Reuse a calculated column in the WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query:

```
SELECT id
    , CASE WHEN id LIKE 'A_SEQ%' THEN 'amber'
    WHEN TestReason = 'itf' THEN 'red'
    ELSE NULL END AS amberRed
FROM db.tbl1
```

I want to either classify something as `red` or `amber` and exclude everything else.

The reason behind this is because if I don't exclude `NULL`s, the resulting dataset is 144,000,000 (144 million) rows deep; if the `NULL`s are excluded, it whittles it down to a mere 878,000.

The general advice that I keep reading is to try this approach but it doesn't work as the column `amberRed` isn't recognised:

```
SELECT id
    , CASE WHEN id LIKE 'A_SEQ%' THEN 'amber'
    WHEN TestReason = 'itf' THEN 'red'
    ELSE NULL END AS amberRed
FROM db.tbl1
WHERE amberRed IS NOT NULL
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server you are unable to use a calculated column in the `WHERE` clause, only in the `ORDER BY` clause.

So you either need a sub-query of some form or you have to repeat the calculation. `CROSS APPLY` is a neat way to accomplish this.

```
SELECT T1.id, X.AmberRed
FROM db.tbl1 T1
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    CASE WHEN T1.id LIKE 'A_SEQ%' THEN 'amber'
    WHEN TestReason = 'itf' THEN 'red'
    ELSE NULL END
)) AS X (AmberRed)
WHERE X.AmberRed IS NOT NULL;
```

But a simple sub-query will also do the job

```
SELECT X.id, X.AmberRed
FROM (
    SELECT T1.id
        , CASE WHEN T1.id LIKE 'A_SEQ%' THEN 'amber'
        WHEN TestReason = 'itf' THEN 'red'
        ELSE NULL END
    FROM db.tbl1 T1
) X
WHERE X.AmberRed IS NOT NULL;
```

Or you can even just repeat the expression if its simple:

```
SELECT T1.id
    , CASE WHEN T1.id LIKE 'A_SEQ%' THEN 'amber'
    WHEN TestReason = 'itf' THEN 'red'
    ELSE NULL END
FROM db.tbl1 T1
WHERE CASE WHEN T1.id LIKE 'A_SEQ%' THEN 'amber'
    WHEN TestReason = 'itf' THEN 'red'
    ELSE NULL END IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: This works nicely. Why doesn't the commonly-suggested method work?

Comment: You just can't use a calculated column name in the `where` clause with SQL Server. I haven't seen your reference, but maybe its for a different database? Or maybe you've seen it used in the `order by` clause - which you can do.

Comment: @Mus Have a look at [A Beginner’s Guide to the True Order of SQL Operations](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/). The _select list_ isn't processed until after the `where` clause, so your calculated value doesn't exist yet. Moving it to the `from` clause (by using `cross apply`) moves it up in the order of processing.