# Alias name shows as Invalid column name when used

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to join two tables and count percentage and show the result by grouping them by alias but the alias name shows as Invalid column

```
SELECT
    Warehouse.warehouse_id,
    CONCAT(Warehouse.state,':', Warehouse.warehouse_alias) AS warehouse_name,
    COUNT(Orders.order_id) AS number_of_orders,
    (SELECT
        COUNT(*)
        FROM Orders)
        AS toatl_orders,
        CASE
            WHEN COUNT(Orders.order_id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders) <=0.20
            THEN 'Fulfilled 0-20% of Orders'
            WHEN COUNT(Orders.order_id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders) >0.20
            AND  COUNT(Orders.order_id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders) <=0.60
            THEN 'Fulfilled 21-60% of Orders'
        ELSE 'Fulfilled more than 60% of Orders'
        END AS fulfillment_summary
FROM Warehouse
LEFT JOIN Orders
    ON Orders.warehouse_id=Warehouse.warehouse_id
GROUP BY
    Warehouse.warehouse_id,
    warehouse_name
HAVING 
    COUNT(Orders.order_id) >0
```

Comment: Its not valid SQL to use an alias name in the `group by` clause only the `order by` clause. Just use a sub-query to make it available.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that new to SQL that's why I removed T-SQL  tag, I tried order by but it makes HAVING Clause error

Comment: You certainly need a group by, but you need to calculate you value in a sub-query so its available to you.

Comment: Thanks for the help I will try other methods I found similar solutions

Comment: Here is what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67864374/how-can-i-reuse-a-calculated-case-column-in-the-where-clause

Answer (score 1):

**Your immediate problem is that you are referring to a calculation from the `SELECT` in the `GROUP BY` clause. You cannot do this.**

Instead, add the individual parts to the `GROUP BY`.

A further improvement is to precalculate the full `Orders` count.

You also have the issue that `COUNT`  is an integer, so you will get integer division instead of a percentage.

> Note that you should use short table aliases to make the query more readable

```sql
DECLARE @OrdersCount int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders);

SELECT
    w.warehouse_id,
    CONCAT(w.state,':', w.warehouse_alias) AS warehouse_name,
    COUNT(o.order_id) AS number_of_orders,
    @OrdersCount AS total_orders,
    CASE
            WHEN COUNT(Orders.order_id) * 1.0 / @OrdersCount <= 0.20
            THEN 'Fulfilled 0-20% of Orders'
            WHEN COUNT(Orders.order_id) * 1.0 / @OrdersCount > 0.20
            AND  COUNT(Orders.order_id) * 1.0 / @OrdersCount <= 0.60
            THEN 'Fulfilled 21-60% of Orders'
        ELSE 'Fulfilled more than 60% of Orders'
        END AS fulfillment_summary
FROM Warehouse w
LEFT JOIN Orders o
    ON o.warehouse_id = w.warehouse_id
GROUP BY
    w.warehouse_id,
    w.state,
    w.warehouse_alias
HAVING 
    COUNT(Orders.order_id) > 0;
```

A different version of the same thing **utilizes `CROSS APPLY` to calculate the grouping field**

```sql
DECLARE @OrdersCount int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders);

SELECT
    w.warehouse_id,
    v.warehouse_name,
    COUNT(o.order_id) AS number_of_orders,
    @OrdersCount AS total_orders,
    CASE
            WHEN COUNT(Orders.order_id) * 1.0 / @OrdersCount <= 0.20
            THEN 'Fulfilled 0-20% of Orders'
            WHEN COUNT(Orders.order_id) * 1.0 / @OrdersCount > 0.20
            AND  COUNT(Orders.order_id) * 1.0 / @OrdersCount <= 0.60
            THEN 'Fulfilled 21-60% of Orders'
        ELSE 'Fulfilled more than 60% of Orders'
        END AS fulfillment_summary
FROM Warehouse w
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    CONCAT(w.state,':', w.warehouse_alias)
) ) v(warehouse_name)
LEFT JOIN Orders o
    ON o.warehouse_id = w.warehouse_id
GROUP BY
    w.warehouse_id,
    v.warehouse_name
HAVING 
    COUNT(Orders.order_id) > 0;
```

Answer (score -2):

Use like below:

```
    SELECT
        Warehouse.warehouse_id,
        CONCAT(Warehouse.state,':', Warehouse.warehouse_alias) AS warehouse_name,
        COUNT(Orders.order_id) AS number_of_orders,
        (SELECT
            COUNT(*)
            FROM Orders)
            AS toatl_orders,
            CASE
                WHEN COUNT(Orders.order_id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders) <=0.20
                THEN 'Fulfilled 0-20% of Orders'
                WHEN COUNT(Orders.order_id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders) >0.20
                AND  COUNT(Orders.order_id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders) <=0.60
                THEN 'Fulfilled 21-60% of Orders'
            ELSE 'Fulfilled more than 60% of Orders'
            END AS fulfillment_summary
    FROM Warehouse
    LEFT JOIN Orders
        ON Orders.warehouse_id=Warehouse.warehouse_id
    GROUP BY
        Warehouse.warehouse_id,
        CONCAT(Warehouse.state,':', Warehouse.warehouse_alias),
(SELECT
            COUNT(*)
            FROM Orders)
            ,
            (CASE
                WHEN COUNT(Orders.order_id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders) <=0.20
                THEN 'Fulfilled 0-20% of Orders'
                WHEN COUNT(Orders.order_id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders) >0.20
                AND  COUNT(Orders.order_id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders) <=0.60
                THEN 'Fulfilled 21-60% of Orders'
            ELSE 'Fulfilled more than 60% of Orders'
            END)
    HAVING 
        COUNT(Orders.order_id) >0
```

Or you can use nested query.