Where Clause on a Converted Date
I'm currently writing a query to pull data from my database to compare what the front end shows. I have to convert the date and time fields so that validation is made easier.
My question is: Is there a way to write a where clause that references the converted date and time? I'd like to limit results based on ET rather than UTC.
CONVERT(DATETIME,t.dateCreated AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time') AS 'Date Created',  -- converting UTC to ET
CAST(CONVERT(DATETIME,SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,t.dateCreated),
DATENAME(TZOFFSET,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))) AS DATE) AS 'Date Created',


As in this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67864374/reuse-a-calculated-column-in-the-where-clause

Of course using a function in your where clause makes your query unsargable and therefore perform badly/.
